# Nesting multiple Closures in Groovy

Tags: groovy, functional-programming, closures

I am having trouble nesting multiple Closures in Groovy. Nesting only one works like a charm:

```
def nestedClosure = { Closure cl -> doSomething { cl() } }
```

But how can I programatically nest multiple closures from e.g. a list of Closures?

Suppose this example:

```
Closure main = { println "Hello world" }

Closure consumer1 = { x -> println("1"); x(); println("1 END") }
Closure consumer2 = { x -> println("2"); x(); println("2 END") }
Closure consumer3 = { x -> println("3"); x(); println("3 END") }
```

I want to somehow chain and nest these consumers to get the output of:

```
1
2
3
Hello world
3 END
2 END
1 END
```

Tried currying, insane loops and googling for quite a while now, but can't seem to get any working idea.

Answer (score 3):

The trick was to curry the last Closure with the deepest nested "main" Closure and consecutively currying the remaining Closures and overwriting main:

```
def main = { println "Hallo" }

Closure consumer1 = { x -> println("1"); x(); println("1 END") }
Closure consumer2 = { x -> println("2"); x(); println("2 END") }
Closure consumer3 = { x -> println("3"); x(); println("3 END") }

def consumers = [consumer1, consumer2, consumer3]

// Nest main in last closure
consumers.reverse().each {
    main = it.curry(main)
}

main()
```

Notce: since I internally used `Consumer<Closure>` to remain argument safety, I needed to curry `Consumer.accept` via Method pointer:

```
def main = { println "Hallo" }

Consumer<Closure> consumer1 = { x -> println("1"); x(); println("1 END") }
Consumer<Closure> consumer2 = { x -> println("2"); x(); println("2 END") }
Consumer<Closure> consumer3 = { x -> println("3"); x(); println("3 END") }

def consumers = [consumer1, consumer2, consumer3]

consumers.reverse().each {
    main = it.&accept.curry(main)
}

main()
```

Comment: For style, not golfing: you could reduce (`inject`) instead of iterating and modifying something captured.

Comment: @cfrick Sounds sophisticated, could you please show an example of that technique?

Comment: Roughly (as in untested): `def mainPrime = consumers.reverse().inject(main, { acc, f -> f.&accept.curry(acc) })`

Comment: Thats marvellous!